# Twitter is making me follow random people

Tags: twitter, followers, follow

Twitter is making me follow random people. After two days of unfollowing them I get another dozens of people in my follow list. Did my account get hacked or something?

Comment: Not hacked and it still happens. Twitter has a problem

Comment: I'm also not hacked (after changing my password and revoking all the app access), and having this same problem. My account starts following random people, sometimes one or two a day.

Answer (score 7):

It seems the possibility you have been hacked is quite high. As the [Twitter Help Center Page](https://support.twitter.com/articles/31796-my-account-has-been-compromised) states, here are some common things that happen when you are hacked:

> - Noticed unexpected Tweets by your account
> - Seen unintended direct messages (DMs) sent from your account
> - Observed other account behaviors you didn't make or approve (like    following, unfollowing, or blocking)
> - Received a notification from us stating that "You recently changed    the email address associated with your Twitter account." (even though 
>     you haven't changed your email address)

[*Source*](https://support.twitter.com/articles/31796-my-account-has-been-compromised)

The Twitter Support page states that you should perform the following steps to remedy the issue:

> 1. **Change your password**
>
>    Please change your password immediately from the Password tab in
>      settings. Please select a strong password you haven't used before. If
>      you can't log in to your account, please see this troubleshooting
>      page.
> 2. **Revoke connections to third-party applications**
>
>    While logged in, visit Apps in your settings. Revoke access for any
>      third-party application that you don't recognize.
> 3. **Update your password in your trusted third-party applications**
>
>    If a trusted external application uses your Twitter password, be sure
>      to update your password in that application. Otherwise, you may be
>      temporarily locked out of your account due to failed login attempts.
>
>    Your account should now be secure, and you shouldn't see the
>      unexpected account behaviors moving forward. If you're still
>      experiencing issues, please file a Support request for assistance.

[*Source*](https://support.twitter.com/articles/31796-my-account-has-been-compromised)

Along with doing this I suggest scanning your computer for malware using a program such as [Malwarebytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/).